# django model field default function calls two times

Tags: django

I've got model FTPUser. Field password populates automatically by function pass_generator.

```
class FTPUser(models.Model):
    ......
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=pass_generator)

def pass_generator(size=12, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    passwd = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    return passwd
```

Model FTPUser is managed in django admin:

```
class FTPUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['password', ]
```

As shown above, field password is read only and when admin creates new instance in FTPUser model he can't change field password, only read it(what I need), vaule of password field generates by function.

**The problem is django calls function pass_generator two times! First time, when inicializes create form and second time whem saves instance to database. So in database we got absolutely different password than was shown to admin!**

I tested to set password filed editable and in that case it works correctly, so I think probles is when password filed is read only it shown as string at creation, not an inpun filed, so on save model FTPUser doesn't get that vaule from creation form and calls function pass_generator second time.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can look into `django signals`. This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save) may help you.

Comment: What do you mean? How signals could help me?

Comment: Instead of using default value, use `pre_save` signal and there assign value from `pass_generator`

Comment: But I need to show generated password to admin

Comment: Now I solve the problem by using jquery, I made password input field read-only, but I think it not very nice solution and I want to solv it on django level